# Is it possible to share the reader between steps using distinct sql objects (string)?

Tags: spring-batch

All, I am trying to read from db tables (2 distinct sql queries) to process them in a batch job and finally store the data in a target table. This is just a prototype so I wanted to try scalable solution using shared readers. Meaning, I want to have one reader method which will be expected to read from the same ds but using dynamic sqls. what I tried was :

```java
        @Bean (destroyMethod="")
        @StepScope
          public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> factTableReader() 
          {

                  JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader = new
                          JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

                          reader.setName("Facts Item Readers/multiple");
                          reader.setDataSource(dataSource); 
                          reader.setSql(sql);
                         // reader.open(this.execContext); 
                          reader.setRowMapper(new EodFactsRowMapper());
                          return reader;

          }
```

I set the value for sql before step call. So, my expectation was that when the stepscoped readers will obtain the sql values. However, the reader did not recognize this kind of setup. So I explored further and understood that stepexecutioncontext could have been used. However, this seemed a tedious task (moreover I could not get it working) as there is complete documentation available to show this behavior. Parameterized statements are not viable as my sqls are completely different. So I finally ended with the below approach in a matter of 2 mins. The original scalable approach had taken me few days but with no luck.

```java
          @Bean (destroyMethod="")
          public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> factTableReader1() 
          {

              System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++INSIDE COMPONENT: READER 1 ++++++++++++++++++++++++");

                  JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader = new
                          JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

                          reader.setName("eod Facts Item Readers/multiple");
                          reader.setDataSource(dataSource); 
                          reader.setSql(sql1);
                         // reader.open(this.execContext); 
                          reader.setRowMapper(new EodFactsRowMapper());
                          return reader;

          }

          @Bean (destroyMethod="")
          public JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> factTableReader2() 
          {

              System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++INSIDE COMPONENT: READER 2 ++++++++++++++++++++++++");


                  JdbcCursorItemReader<Map<String, Object>> reader = new
                          JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

                          reader.setName("eod Facts Item Readers/multiple");
                          reader.setDataSource(dataSource); 
                          reader.setSql(sql2);
                         // reader.open(this.execContext); 
                          reader.setRowMapper(new EodFactsRowMapper());
                          return reader;

          }
```

I map the column via code so there is no issue with rowmapper or processor.

Any help in achieving what I am trying to do here will be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to try scalable solution using shared readers.

Shared state is the first enemy of scalability. I would keep things simple and efficient by using two readers (each with its own sql query) rather then trying to share a single reader and deal with concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. I had to write two readers to make this happen. Ideally I would have loved a method which would take parameters to minimize the code lines.

Comment: The real issue here is using a shared reader or distinct instances, and the solution is the second approach . Now how to achieve that without code duplication is another concern, but that's not an issue: 1)Using XML config you can create an abstract bean definition for the reader with common properties and override only the sql property in concrete definitions 2) With Java config you can create an abstract class with common code and two concrete classes with specific config to avoid duplication. If my answer helped, please accept it. Thank you.